# Easily configure categorical variables

Tags: python, statsmodels, patsy

I have a categorical variable, let's say `cat_var` which can assume the following values: `cat_var = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

I run a series of regressions and [`patsy`](https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API-reference.html#categorical-coding-ref) makes it easy to describe a regression: `regr= " y ~ x + C(cat_var)`

I was wondering what the easiest way to tune the use of categorical variable is .
For example, let's say I would like to have `patsy` create dummies only for `"A"`, `"B"`, ie `"C"` and `"D"` are treated as one single group. I could remap `cat_var` to another set of value, but is there some sugar in `patsy` to do this task already?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no ready made tools for this.

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015038/python-quantreg-categorical and related discussion see thread with https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pystatsmodels/awZU2jM6xr0/gthF1t1QNksJ

Efficient recipes would be welcome. I would use pandas to create a new "CD" variable..